# How can I verify whether my OpenPGP key revocation was uploaded successfully?

Tags: thunderbird, pgp, openpgp, enigmail

I just revoked my old PGP key using Enigmail in Thunderbird. I uploaded the revoked key and deleted it afterwards.

Now I'm wondering, how can I verify that it is really revoked so that other users are getting informed about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check an [arbitrary server in the key server network](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/). To specify a key, remember to prefix the key ID with `0x` (which is expected by the SKS key server software for denoting key IDs). For example, my own key is found by [searching for `0xa4ff2279`](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0xa4ff2279).

If your revocation certificate is not visible (yet), don't worry: while the key servers synchronize with each other, this process takes some time. Usually in the range of minutes, but it could also take some hours sometimes. If you're not under time pressure, just check back tomorrow.